# Smooth Div Scroll not correctly displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement smooth div scroll, the "Clickable Logo Parade" in particular: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.html

And I got it working in a blank page perfectly exactly the way I want it to, but when I insert it in my current layout it doesnt work properly.. I am assuming something is interfering with it?

Any help?

This is what I added into my css:

```
#logoParade
{
width: 628px;
height: 75px;
position: relative;
}

#logoParade div.scrollableArea a
{
display: block;
float: left;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

This is the jQuery I have added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#logoParade").smoothDivScroll({ 
    autoScrollingMode: "always", 
    autoScrollingDirection: "endlessLoopRight", 
    autoScrollingStep: 1, 
    autoScrollingInterval: 25 
});

// Logo parade event handlers
$("#logoParade").bind("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
}).bind("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
});

});
</script>
```

And these documents im including:

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Latest version (3.0.6) of jQuery Mouse Wheel by Brandon Aaron
     You will find it here: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos -->
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- jQuery Kinectic (1.5) used for touch scrolling -->
<script src="js/jquery.kinetic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Smooth Div Scroll 1.3 minified-->
<script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As well as of course actual jquery..

I uploaded me trying to implement it here you can have a look:
http://www.mintystudios.co.uk/clients/naghmeh/

And here is working version in a blank page..:
http://www.mintystudios.co.uk/clients/naghmeh/1/

Anyone know why it isnt working in the implemented version?

Comment: jQuery isn't loading. "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function" Get jQuery loading, and it'll probably run.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem; replace it with your script.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#logoParade").smoothDivScroll({ 
        autoScrollingMode: "always", 
        autoScrollingDirection: "endlessLoopRight", 
        autoScrollingStep: 1, 
        autoScrollingInterval: 25 
    });

    // Logo parade event handlers
    $("#logoParade").bind("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
    }).bind("mouseout", function() {
        $(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
    });

});
    </SCRIPT>
```